# Conveying the idea of "tricky"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

The other day I wanted to say to my students

> That was easy, here's a trickier one.

I said

> Ça c'était facile, en voici un plus délicat.

But I think délicat is of higher register than tricky. Dictionaries give as translations of tricky, depending on the context, rusé, difficile, among other words. I am wondering if there are other words or expressions that better convey the idea of tricky as given, for example, here

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tricky

> (1) If you describe a task or problem as tricky, you mean that it is
>   difficult to do or deal with.

Comment: So many good answers here below, it's going to be hard choosing the best one

Comment: @LaurentS. Yes! Tough indeed. I wish I could choose more the one:-)!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the  adjective *vicieux* if you want to convey a slighty humorous touch. It carries a mildly "sadistic" touch.

> C'était un problème facile. En voici un plus vicieux.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99807/discussion-on-answer-by-greg-conveying-the-idea-of-tricky).

Answer (score 9):

`Délicat` is fine in this context, no problem.

But in general in such situation we would use `piège` (or `piégeux`), which litterally means trap (or its associated adjective).
It means there is a trap, that is the hidden difficulty, that you can deal with by being careful. Both can be used in oral discussion, not so much when writing.

Depending on the context you can also use `technique` (which means technical).
You can use `technique` when one needs specific (technical) skills to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 8):

If you want really a lower register, try 'casse-gueule'.

Answer (score 5):

If for whatever reason you want to dazzle your students with some cheesy juxtapositions of [outdated] slang, you could consider:

> Ça c'était du/un velours, maintenant passons à autre chose de plus
>   épineux.

or (but I'm not sure about which demonstrative pronouns to use with this one

> Ça (Cela/Celui-la?), c'était du/un velours mais par contre, ceci
>   (celui-ci?), c'est [plus] coton.

cf:
"C'est du velours (fam.). C'est chose aisée." and "b) Argot α) ,,Travail facile``... c'était un velours"
([both from *TLFi*'s entry for **velours**](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/velours))

"Qui présente des difficultés, qui donne beaucoup de mal, de peine."
 (from [*TLFi*'s entry for **épineux**](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/epineux))

"− Loc. arg. C'est coton. C'est difficile."
(from [*TLFi*'s entry for **coton**](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/coton))

Comment: C'est évidemment vous qui avez raison mais, curieusement, j'avais toujours entendu dire "***pas** coton*" pour évoquer la difficulté. C'est à dire en fait... tout l'inverse.

Comment: Aussi, en opposition comme dans vos exemples on pourrait avoir "*l'autre paire de manches*"...

Comment: @aCOSwt Justement ma femme francaise vient de me dire qu'elle est completement d'accord avec vous (ie, que "c'est pas coton" = "c'est pas de la tarte")

Comment: @aCOSwt Vu que l'exemple en *TLFi* de "c'est coton" est deja vieux et en plus que ca fait longtemps que le *TLFI* n'a pas ete mis au jour, je crois que ma 2eme suggestion risque d'etre faux et que vous et ma femme avez raison.

Comment: *C'est coton* et *c'est pas coton*, c'est kif-kif...

Comment: @aCOSwt Je viens de voir votre commentaire sur "l'autre paire de manches" et je le trouve vraiment genial !  Ca marcherait, tout seul, pas seulement pour capter la notion de "par contre" mais aussi celle de "plus difficile/trickier"sans rien dire de plus.

Answer (score 5):

Il n'apparait pas dans toutes les excellentes contributions précédentes... bizarre... car, à mon époque, dans mon coin, l'équivalent très exact de *tricky* était :

**Trapu.**

C'est d'ailleurs le sens que lui donne le [TLF (B.2)](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trapu)

Certain disaient *trap's* pour faire genre.

Ce trapu qualifiait une difficulté intellectuelle. Soluble à la condition d'aller se chercher. D'aller faire carburer les neurones.

Quand la difficulté était plus de l'ordre de la besogne (nombreuses heures de travail ou lignes d'écriture requises) alors là... trapu laissait sa place à :

***Cogné***

Comment: Mais oui bien sûr...  trapu ! Par contre *cogné* je ne connaissais pas ! Par contre le TLF, c'est pas forcément une référence. Alors...

Comment: Honnêtement, en tant que locuteur natif, ces deux termes sonnent vraiment étrange.

Comment: @GrasDouble : Sans remettre en question votre droit le plus strict... et out of interest... l'adverbe *étrange**ment*** il '*sonne*' lui aussi "*vraiment étrange*" ?

Answer (score 4):

- You can also say  "Qui donne **du fil à retordre**"

Answer (score 4):

If we agree that "tricky" implies that whatever you have to deal  with is difficult because it has no obvious solution and that it needs a lot of attention, then here are two proposals:

- Ça c'était facile, maintenant passons à autre chose de **moins évident**.
- Ça c'était facile, maintenant passons à autre chose de **plus complexe**.

Et si on veut faire dans un registre beaucoup plus familier que le très sérieux *vicieux* déjà donné par @Greg il y a *[vicelard](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vicelard)*.

- Ça c'était fastoche, en voici un plus vicelard.

Answer (score 3):

On peut utiliser l'adjectif « astucieux » mais appliqué à une personne ou ce qu'elle fait.

- Ça c'était facile, en voici un qui demande un raisonnement (beaucoup) plus astucieux.

Answer (score 2):

If you were conveying the idea that the problem wasn't straightforward, a good translation could have been "tordu".